# Ошибка при копировании объекта

Tags: c++, opengl

Перегрузил для моделей оператор присваивания. Всё работает, но при копировании во время работы программы opengl сообщает об ошибке

```
Debug message (1282): Error has been generated. GL error GL_INVALID_OPERATION in EnableVertexAttribArray: (ID: 1580284243)
```

Не смог найти инфу по ошибке кроме наиболее общей, но предполагаю, что при присвоении Mesh одного объекта другому, вызов glEnableVertexAttribArray(_index); либо пытается обратиться к уже существующим старым атрибутам, либо записывает новые, но обращается по старому адресу

Если кто-нибудь что-нибудь знает, подскажите, что идёт не так

```
Object& operator=(const Object<T>& other) {

    this->mesh = other.mesh;
    this->matrix = other.matrix;
    this->local = other.local;
    return *this;

}


Mesh& operator=(const Mesh<T>& other) {

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &IBO);
    this->_vendex = other._vendex;
    this->load();
    return *this;

}


void load() {
    this->genVAO();
    this->genVBO();
    this->genIBO();
    
    this->enableAttributes();
    
    this->result_size = _vendex.v_size() * sizeof(T);
}


void enableAttributes() {
    size_t _size = 0;
    GLenum _type = GL_FLOAT;

    for(size_t _index = 0; _index < T::size; ++_index) {
        GLvoid* offset = T::get_offset(_index, _size, _type);

        glVertexAttribPointer(_index, _size, _type, GL_FALSE, sizeof(T), offset);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(_index);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}


Vendex& operator=(const Vendex<T>& other) {
    this->vertex.clear();
    this->index.clear();
    for(auto &i : other.vertex) this->vertex.push_back(i);
    for(auto &i : other.index) this->index.push_back(i);
    
    this->update();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: ¿А вас не смущает, что оба объекта останутся с одинаковыми полями `_vendex` и т.д. ?

Comment: @user7860670 вроде не смущает, у класса Vendex перегружен оператор присваивания

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашёл источник ошибки: вызов glEnableVertexAttribArray(0) в конце отрисовки, проблема решилась после комментирования строки

```
void update::Clear() {
    glFlush();
    //glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glUseProgram(0); 
}
```